# How can we download the complete webpage data to spreadsheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, openoffice-calc

how can i download the content in the webpage to spreadsheet Below is my code which downloads only excel sheet data but it doesnot download the other content that is in web page how can i download the complete webpage data

```
protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Details.ods");
                    Response.ContentType = "vnd.oasis.opendocument.text";
                    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                    GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
                    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                    Response.End();


                }
                public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
                {

                }
            }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of "text"? You declare it but don't use it.

Comment: I assume ODS is the OpenOffice of "Excel"?

Comment: And finally your Session[] variable seems to only be used to fill a ASP:Label control. Where is the code to show your're saving the messages into an ODS file?

Comment: Have you tried my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your

```
<br>
```

with

```
<br/>
```